# C#: Method's declaring type and the owner type's class must be the same ERROR, how to resolve this?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, export-to-excel, excel-interop

I am looking to **export a data table to Excel from C#**. For this I looked up example codes to run but when I tried implementing the codes using Interop Excel. **While the code does run** (can open/create a workbook, open/create a worksheet, rename worksheets, save the results down), **I cannot alter the cells**. Neither value changes nor formatting changes work for me. It saves down a blank Excel file with the changes to the worksheets lets say. After asking for help here at [C# COM Interop Excel: How to write to cells from C# using Interop Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68666728/c-sharp-com-interop-excel-how-to-write-to-cells-from-c-sharp-using-interop-exce) I found that while I could create buttons that worked separately it didn't run in my codebase still.

The error I find is that **when I initiate the Excel app, Workbook and Worksheet objects I get a Method's declaring type and the owner type's class must be the same error** when checking the variables window, but the code runs with the aforementioned outcome.

Please see below the code I ran (ExcelTest.Test()): I am using Rider but tried the results and failed in Visual Studio as well. Also tried from multiple computers and didn't work. .NET framework is 4.0.3 and the Interop package installed is the most recent 15.0.4795 (while also Microsoft Office Core is installed with the most recent 15.0.0 version). CSV writing did work.

I do not know what else to try, if I can give further context I am very happy to. Thank you for your help!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ExcelTest
{

    public static class ExcelTest
    {
        public static void Test()
        {
            string[,] data = CreateTestData();
        
            string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Test123.xlsx");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("filename: " + filename);
            WriteToExcel(filename, data);
        }
        
        public static void WriteToExcel(string filename, string[,] data)
        {
            //Write cell value using row number and column number

            //*Note: Excel cells, can also be referenced by name, such as "E2" by using "Range"
            //
            //       All indices in Excel (rowNumber, columnNumber, etc...) start with 1 
            //       The format is: <rowNumber>, <columnNumber>
            //       The top left-most column, is: 1,1


            object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            Excel.Application excelApp = null;
            Excel.Range range = null;
            Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
            Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;

            int worksheetCount = 0;

            try
            {
                //create new instance
                excelApp = new Excel.Application();

                //suppress displaying alerts (such as prompting to overwrite existing file)
                excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;

                //set Excel visability
                excelApp.Visible = true;

                //disable user control while modifying the Excel Workbook
                //to prevent user interference
                //only necessary if Excel application Visibility property = true
                //excelApp.UserControl = false;

                //disable
                //excelApp.Calculation = Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;

                //if writing/updating a large amount of data
                //disable screen updating by setting value to false
                //for better performance.
                //re-enable when done writing/updating data, if desired
                //excelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;

                //create new workbook
                workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

                //get number of existing worksheets
                worksheetCount = workbook.Sheets.Count;

                //add a worksheet and set the value to the new worksheet
                worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet) workbook.Sheets.Add();

                if (data != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        int rowNum = i + 1;

                        for (int j = 0; j < data.GetLength(1); j++)
                        {
                            int colNum = j + 1;

                            //set cell location that data needs to be written to
                            //range = worksheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum];

                            //set value of cell
                            //range.Value = data[i,j];

                            //set value of cell
                            worksheet.Cells[rowNum, colNum] = data[i, j];
                        }
                    }
                }

                //enable
                //excelApp.Calculation = Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;
                //excelApp.ScreenUpdating = true;

                //save Workbook - if file exists, overwrite it
                workbook.SaveAs(filename, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
                    System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Status: Complete. " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errMsg = "Error (WriteToExcel) - " + ex.Message;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(errMsg);

                if (ex.Message.StartsWith("Cannot access read-only document"))
                {
                    
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (workbook != null)
                {
                    //close workbook
                    workbook.Close();

                    //release all resources
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(workbook);
                }

                if (excelApp != null)
                {
                    //close Excel
                    excelApp.Quit();

                    //release all resources
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
                }
            }
        }

        public static string[,] CreateTestData()
        {
            string[,] data = new string[6, 4];

            data[0, 0] = "First Name";
            data[0, 1] = "Last Name";
            data[0, 2] = "Full Name";
            data[0, 3] = "Salary";

            data[1, 0] = "John";
            data[1, 1] = "Smith";

            data[2, 0] = "Tom";
            data[2, 1] = "Brown";

            data[3, 0] = "Sue";
            data[3, 1] = "Thomas";

            data[4, 0] = "Jane";
            data[4, 1] = "Jones";

            data[5, 0] = "Adam";
            data[5, 1] = "Johnson";

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the exact error you get, and do you know on what line of code?

Comment: Just ran the code in your question it successfully created a file with data in - https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Pt3.png

Comment: I guess it's a versioning problem with the Interop. Set **Specific Version** to **No** for the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` reference in the properties window. And also set **Copy Local** and **Embed Interop Types** both to **Yes**.

Comment: There is no error, the code does run it just doesn't alter any of the cells. I see a blank sheet while the workbook with the worksheet is saved down to the appropriate location. If I create a separate file it does run, but when including it in my codebase as a unit test it gives the above "error" when debugging it and looking at the worksheet, workbook and application variables

Comment: Olivier, could you elaborate further on where can I alter these settings? Managing the NuGet packages under dependencies I didnt find the aforementioned settings

Comment: In one of my .NET 5 projects the interop assemblies are referenced under (in the Solution Explorer) Your Project > Dependencies > Assemblies. Click on all the assemblies there and you will see these properties in the Properties window. In addition to Microsoft.Office.Interop.* I also have a reference to `office` and `Microsoft.Vbe.Interop` (only required when manipulating VBA modules). But there may be other ways (e.g. NuGet) to integrate the interop assemblies.

Comment: First, I would like to say thank you for your continued help! I havent been able to locate the properties but searching for it found the error, indeed a version-related one, namely: "NU1701  'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel 15.0.4795.1000' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.2'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project."

Comment: Also, when trying to get to the properties you mentioned I found this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/690930f1-7856-4f5f-b073-6cf2c40baa19/microsoftofficeinteropexcel-with-net-core?forum=netfxbcl but I had trouble with referencing the excel object library as I can only seem to add references from inside the project or through managing NuGet packages (I use/checked both Visual Studio and Rider) Thanks in advance!