# Create an Excel File from a dataGridView

Tags: c#, excel, performance, datagridview, excel-interop

I have a dataGridView in a WindowsForms. I want a button to export this dataGridView to an Excel Worksheet.

```cs
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Application ExcelApp;
Excel.Workbook ExcelWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet ExcelWorkSheet;

ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
ExcelWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
ExcelWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)ExcelWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; ++j)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
            ExcelWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception ex) { /*somestuff*/ }
// save ExcelWorkbook
```

This code works. But unfortunately the time complexity is bad. So I'm forced to implement a progressbar. If i wouldn't do it, the user would be thinking the program crashed, while exporting a big datagridview. Needless to say, this will of course slow down the export even more. (progressbar code is not included in this question)

I wonder, if there is a method to export a datagrid to an excel faster.

Comment: Interop is notoriously slow. Are you stuck using Interop? There are better and faster third-party Excel libraries. Some are free for non-commercial use. I suggest looking at EPPlus if you have the option to do so.

Comment: If you'd like to use a MS product, consider NuGet package [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/). Also see [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK), [Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5), and [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk).

Comment: As someone else stated, interop is slow. It's even slower on subsequent operations if it's not properly disposed of. The code you posted doesn't show how you're disposing of your objects. The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68667926/10024425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hints to use another third-party library.
I was giving EPPLus a chance.

Here is the code:

```cs
private void ExportWithEPPlus(string filepath)
{
    using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet 1");
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; ++j)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[j, i];
                    worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].Value = cell.Value;
                }
            }
        catch (Exception ex) { /*somestuff*/ }
        finally
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@filepath);
            excelPackage.SaveAs(fi);            
        }
    }
}
```

It's fast like hell. The drawback is: It's memory hungry.