# Exporting DataGrid to Excel missing reference

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, export-to-excel

Currently attempting to export datagrid to an excel file.Right now as my code is the only thing that gets exported are the Headers. Below is the datagrid

```
<Page x:Class="ABSCCoastRefining.EndOfYear"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ABSCCoastRefining"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="EndOfYear">
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ItemCollectionViewSources" CollectionViewType="{x:Type ListCollectionView}"/>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="#FFD1F1D1" Margin="0,-10,0,10">
    <TextBlock Text="End Of Year" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="22,10,0,0" Width="124" Background="White"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgEndOfYear" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        DataContext="{StaticResource ItemCollectionViewSources}"
        Margin="65,112,285,237" 
        Background="#FFE0F0E0"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CanUserAddRows="False"
        CanUserDeleteRows="False"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
        IsReadOnly="True"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem ="False" Width="450">
        


        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Calendar Year" Binding="{Binding CalendarYear}" Width="Auto" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Month" Binding="{Binding MonthName}" Width="Auto" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Gallons" Binding="{Binding SumGal, StringFormat=N0}" Width="Auto" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

And below is the code for the click event to export the data. dgEndOfYear.Items[i].**Cells** is causing issues and compiler states I am missing a reference I have made several attempts to resolve this on my own but have had no luck any help would be appreciated.

```
private void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // creating Excel Application  
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        // creating new WorkBook within Excel application  
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
        // creating new Excelsheet in workbook  
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet worksheet = null;
        // see the excel sheet behind the program  
        app.Visible = true;
        // get the reference of first sheet. By default its name is Sheet1.  
        // store its reference to worksheet  
        worksheet = workbook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
        worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
        // changing the name of active sheet  
        worksheet.Name = "Exported from gridview";
        // storing header part in Excel  
        for (int i = 1; i < dgEndOfYear.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[1, i] = dgEndOfYear.Columns[i - 1].Header;
        }
        // storing Each row and column value to excel sheet  
        for (int i = 0; i < dgEndOfYear.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dgEndOfYear.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = dgEndOfYear.Items[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
        // save the application  
        workbook.SaveAs("c:\\output.xls", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        // Exit from the application  
        app.Quit();
    }
```

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72794540/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/68667926/10024425.

Comment: Don't attempt to interact directly with the DataGrid. The DataGrid should be bound to something such as an `ObservableCollection`, `DataTable`, etc...- interact with whatever the DataGrid is bound to.